# Can the SoftIRQ prempt currently running the same SoftIRQ with Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, spinlock, softirq

I am working on a performance improvement of a driver and should consider the possibility of deadlock. In a SoftIRQ context, spin_lock will be held and protect some variable. In this case, should I use spin_lock or spin_lock_bh? spin_lock_bh sounds like safer, but I have a general question about SoftIRQ implementation.

- the same softIRQ function can be scheduled on the same CPU during the execution of the SoftIRQ -> we need to use spin_lock_bh in the SoftIRQ
- the same softIRQ function can be scheduled on the other CPU, but not the same CPU -> we may use spin_lock in the SoftIRQ

What is true from the above statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Linux Kernel Development](http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch07lev1sec2) (2nd edition):

> A softirq never preempts another softirq.

The reason is simple: during softIRQ **software interrupts are disabled**.

So it is sufficient to use plain `spin_lock()` in a softIRQ function.